# Is it possible for a race condition in a program that runs one instruction at a time?

Tags: race-condition

I could not find anything to explain this situation in detail, about race conditions.

Comment: Yes. Multithreaded programs on mainstream CPUs only run one instruction at a time (well, grossly speaking). The race conditions occur when the sequence of singly-executed instructions (again, grossly speaking) interleave in conflicting ways.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by running one instruction at a time? @user2864740 is right, but I suspect that's not what you meant.

Comment: This explains it pretty good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, When a computer is being developed, it is usually simulated first by a program that executes one instruction at a time. Even multiprocessors are simulated strictly sequentially in the same way.

Is it possible for a competing condition to occur even though there are no simultaneous events as in this case?